# How to add manytomany relation in other class . In my case in InfoCreateView class

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making a CV page,
I want to link my **Skill**, **Language** etc class(table) to Main **Person** table/class,
But for that, I need to submit skill table first because my person table contains the foreign key for skills.
But as per CV form name & personal info comes first.
Also, I can put the whole form on one page but I want to go to the next page for each sub information, so is it possible to pass the request data from one class-based view to another class-based view.

**models.py**

```
     from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.conf import settings
import datetime


class Workexperience(models.Model):
    work = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,
                max_length=256,
                help_text='eg: Juniorengineer: at L&T ')
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False, default=1 )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.work

class Education(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    college = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=200)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False, default=1 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school

class Skills(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(
                max_length=256,
                help_text='Add skills sperated by commas eg: programming, Matlab')
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False, default=1 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill


class Languages(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(
                max_length=256,
                help_text='Add language sperated by commas eg: English, Gujarati')
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False, default=1 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            help_text='Enter a name (e.g. Harry Virani)',
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "It must be greater than 1 character")]
    )
    picture = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True,
            help_text='The MIMEType of the file')

    profession = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "It must be greater than 1 character")]
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    phone = models.CharField(
            max_length=15,
            help_text='Enter a phone number like this (e.g. +91000000000)',
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(10, "It must be greater than 10 character")] )


    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200,
                help_text='enter your facebook URL'    )
    instagram = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200,
                help_text='enter your instagram link URL'  )
    linkedin = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200,
                help_text='enter your Linked link URL'     )

    skill =  models.ManyToManyField(Skills, related_name='skills',  default=1)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Languages, related_name='languages', default=1)
    edu = models.ManyToManyField(Education,  default=1,related_name='edu' )
    work = models.ManyToManyField(Workexperience,default=1, blank=True, related_name='works')


    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

I want to save it in another class which is for creating skill & other models.

```
  class PersonCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'MYP/form.html'
    success_url =  'MYP:myp_create_info'
    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        personform = PersonForm()
        ctx = { 'personform': personform}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
    def post(self, request, pk=None) :
        # if 'personform' in request.POST:
        personform = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)

        if not personform.is_valid():
            ctx = {'personform': personform}
            return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
        pform = personform.save(commit=False)
        #adding onwer
        pform.owner = self.request.user
        pform.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url, pform.id)

class InfoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'MYP/form2.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('MYP:all')
    def get(self, request, pk):
        person = get_object_or_404(Person,id=pk)
        skill= SkillsForm()
        skill_list = Skills.objects.filter(person=person)
        ctx = { 'skill':skill, 'skill_list':skill_list }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if 'skill' in request.POST:
            skill = SkillsForm(request.POST or None)
            if not skill.is_valid() :
                ctx = { 'skill':skill}
                return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
            person = get_object_or_404(Person,id=pk)
            print(person)
            skill = Skills(skill=request.POST['skill'], person=person)
            skill.save()
            print(skill.person)
        return redirect('MYP:myp_create_info', pk=pk)
```

forms.py

```
    class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    max_upload_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    max_upload_limit_text = naturalsize(max_upload_limit)

    # Call this 'picture' so it gets copied from the form to the in-memory model
    # It will not be the "bytes", it will be the "InMemoryUploadedFile"
    # because we need to pull out things like content_type
    picture = forms.FileField(required=False, label='File to Upload <= '+max_upload_limit_text)
    upload_field_name = 'picture'

    # Hint: this will need to be changed for use in the ads application :)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'profession', 'picture', 'address', 'email', 'phone','facebook','linkedin','instagram']  # Picture is manual

    # Validate the size of the picture
    def clean(self) :
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pic = cleaned_data.get('picture')
        if pic is None : return
        if len(pic) > self.max_upload_limit:
            self.add_error('picture', "File must be < "+self.max_upload_limit_text+" bytes")

    # Convert uploaded File object to a picture
    def save(self, commit=True) :
        instance = super(PersonForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # We only need to adjust picture if it is a freshly uploaded file
        f = instance.picture   # Make a copy
        if isinstance(f, InMemoryUploadedFile):  # Extract data from the form to the model
            bytearr = f.read();
            instance.content_type = f.content_type
            instance.picture = bytearr  # Overwrite with the actual image data

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance

class WorkexperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Workexperience
        fields = ['work']


class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = ['school','college']

class SkillsForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Skills
        fields = ['skill']

class LanguagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Languages
        fields = ['language']
```

Ignore the rest of the code it is just for image handling....
This is what I want to do but I know it is the wrong format
I want to just add id for everything later.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you add your `ForeignKey` to `Person` in `Skill` ? Then a person could have 0, 1 or more skills linked to him and that would let you use Inline formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: I have edited my model & views , also i read ilnine formsets, Also i want to add multiple skills by one person, can u suggest anything?

Comment: So you mean one skill can be shared by multiple users and one user can have multiple skills ? If that's true, you should only keep the `ManyToManyField` in your `Person` model and remove the `ForeignKeys` added in Skill, Workexperience, Education, Language.
Then I suggest you to have a first form to create your person, and another one to add skills, wor experiences, educations, languages. The user could create new one or select existing ones.

Comment: check out my views.py   Can i seprate by comas it with the help of this function of I have do something else. ?  I removed person ForeignKeys from models.

Comment: Yes it's possible to do it like you have done in your views, but I believe it makes more sense to have one `Skill` instance for one skill since several persons could have the same skill. This is a database normalization.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). So I think you should rename `skill` by `name` (of the skill) in your `Skill` model.

Comment: but then I have to add it manually & it will limit the skills to only that i have added

Comment: What do you mean by "add it manually" ? You can have a first form to select extisting skills (that other persons have created) and add them in your manytomany `skills` relation from `Person`. And you can have a second form to create a new `Skil`l and add it directly in the `person.skills`

Comment: then how can I call person.skill in another class?.

Comment: I have made changes to my view.py  now tell me how can I fill manytomanyfield  in my infocreate class. also I will make my rest of filed added same as this. It will allow me to add multiple skills & language. I will add DONE buttuon which will redirect me to main page.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your models are messed up. Here is how I would have write them :

```
class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    work = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        max_length=256,
        help_text='eg: Juniorengineer: at L&T'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.work


class Education(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    college = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school


class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        help_text='Add a skill name (eg: Programming)'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        help_text='Add a language name (eg: Gujarati)'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text='Enter a name (e.g. Harry Virani)',
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "It must be greater than 1 character")]
    )
    
    # [...Other fields...]
    
    skills =  models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='persons', blank=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='persons', blank=True)
    educations = models.ManyToManyField(Education, related_name='persons', blank=True)
    work_experiences = models.ManyToManyField(WorkExperience, related_name='persons', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then I need to see your `forms.py` to better understand how you handle it in your view.

Comment: I add ForeignKeys of person because,  it will let me call a particular  skill via person.